# seaborn scatter plot with column strings as yticks

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot with the column strings as tricks and having the data in a descending order.
Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
data = {'Type':  ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'],
        'Score': ['7.6', '6.4', '7.9', '5.5', '8.0']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Type','Score'])
```

Desired Output

```
Fifth |                  *
Third |                 *
First |                *
Second|        *
Fourth|   *
       5     6     7     8     9
```

Sorry for the bad illustration. Can anyone help me with this visualisation please? Any support is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do so:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = {'Type':  ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'],
        'Score': ['7.6', '6.4', '7.9', '5.5', '8.0']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Type','Score'])
df.sort_values(by=['Score'], inplace=True)
print(df)


sns.scatterplot(x=df["Score"], y=df["Type"])
plt.show()
```

Which produces this graph:

[image]